# How can I reattach already spawned child process with node js?

Tags: node.js

I am creating an application with electron which is responsible to start and stop some child processes. I am also not experienced about this topics.

When I create a child process with spawn, then shut down my application, child processes still must keep alive and there is no problem here also. They are working well.

The problem is, when I restart my application, I don't know how to reattach/resubscribe this process again to learn if it's still working or not. (I am using find-process npm package to check if process is alive but it does not provide a reattach mechanism) And I have to listen it's events, It can crash after a while it started even I restarted my electron application. I mean child.stderr.on('data'... things are lost when I restart my electron application.

How can I reattach a spawned process with node js? I have to provide this windows and linux.

Comment: I think this is not possible since after closing your application you destroy everything that was  used to spawn the process and all kind of information (memory adresses, etc..) A workaround for this chould be "zero config" network discovering of the process and messaging over sockets/tcp/upd. On linux you could use `/proc/<pid>/fd/...` to communicate with the child process

Comment: @Marc I heard some stuff related with pipes but I still don't know how to proceed. I guess for a workaround I will check if process id is still alive or not with in some timer function. This is a very shitty way that I really don't want to implement. Thank you.

Comment: What if you dont "close" all windows (node.js) process ? Just keep the "main" electron process running in the backgrond (like a service) and keep there all child process stored/referenced. TBH i have no clue if pipeing with/on windows works

Comment: @Marc It's a good idea but If my node service will be killed somehow (updating node etc.), I will be in same scenario again

Comment: I belive thats a edge case, where you should tell the user any way to restart thier computer. Beside that "Zero conf" approach, nothing better comes to my mind as solution.